# how can I make Elmah.io integrate with my custom membership provider in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-membershipprovider, elmah.mvc

I installed Elmah.io properly but it doesnt work.

Visual studio gives 6 messages like; Could not find schema information for the element 'security' and 'errorlog' and 'elmah' and 'type' and logid and 'allowremoteaccess' .

how can i make it work?

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false"  type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="deneme" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=THERMALTAKE\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=Tanimlama;Integrated Security=true;"/>      
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomMembershipProvider"                                                 type="membership_kendiyazdigim.Security.CustomMembershipProvider"   connectionStringName="deneme"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordAttemptWindow="10" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" cacheTimeoutInMinutes="5"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="membership_kendiyazdigim.Security.CustomRoleProvider" cacheTimeoutInMinutes="5"/>
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules></system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer><elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false"/>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.Io.ErrorLog, Elmah.Io" LogId="8b3ab986-ccfe-4099-ac3c-790942e77488"/>
  </elmah><location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->  
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location></configuration>

and this is my global logger filter...

public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
    }
}


public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if(context.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a problem with elmah.io or ELMAH in general? Could you share your web.config file?

Comment: (i am kinda new to programming)... i only tried Elmah.io for now. I added web.config.

Comment: Your web.config looks fine. If you ignore the error in Visual Studio and try to throw an exception in your code, the error should be shown in elmah.io.

Comment: By the way you should never show you log id to others. Anyone can access your error log now. Please create a new log and use the new log id instead.

Comment: nope it doesnt still work...(thanks for the warning but i have already made up the log id and then wrote here)...

Comment: i have added my global filter for elmah...

Comment: Are you using Web API or straight MVC?

Comment: straight MVC...well i tried just elmah not elmah.io this time and it still doesnt work either. when i enter elmah.axd it gives 404 not a data about error log. so i decided to postpone to fix this issue for now and think out of box later...

Comment: i installed elmah.mvc and now it is working without adding any global filter and can see error log information by writing just elmah(not elmah.axd) to the url bar.